# How can I connect to an SMB share from a Mac using a specific port?

Tags: macos, networking, network-shares, smb

I'm trying to connect to an SMB share on a Windows machine from a Mac. The SMB is running on port 445. Apparently the Mac is trying to connect on ports 137 through 139.

How can I configure my Mac client to connect on port 445?

Comment: Have you verified that port 445 is open on the Windows machine? You an test at the command line with `telnet 192.168.0.4 445`.

Comment: Indeed it is...

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the port number to the URL.

From the "Go" menu in Finder, choose "Connect to Server..." (or simply hit command-K).

In the "Server Address:" field, enter

```
smb://192.168.0.4:445/
```

(replacing the IP address as appropriate)

Comment: Unfortunately that's the first thing I tried! Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

What version of OS X are you using?  I tried this on my Mac (v10.6.4), and it tried port 445 first, and only tried 139 when it got no answer over 445.  Here's a tcpdump of me (at 172.20.6.3), trying to connect to "smb://1.1.1.1" (which doesn't exist):

```
Gordons-MBP:~ gordon$ sudo tcpdump -q -ien1 -n tcp port 137 or 138 or 139 or 445 
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on en1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
18:17:17.732221 IP 172.20.6.3.60852 > 1.1.1.1.445: tcp 0
18:17:18.705177 IP 172.20.6.3.60852 > 1.1.1.1.445: tcp 0
18:17:19.706158 IP 172.20.6.3.60852 > 1.1.1.1.445: tcp 0
18:17:19.732350 IP 172.20.6.3.60853 > 1.1.1.1.139: tcp 0
18:17:20.707090 IP 172.20.6.3.60853 > 1.1.1.1.139: tcp 0
18:17:20.707209 IP 172.20.6.3.60852 > 1.1.1.1.445: tcp 0
18:17:21.708314 IP 172.20.6.3.60853 > 1.1.1.1.139: tcp 0
18:17:21.708435 IP 172.20.6.3.60852 > 1.1.1.1.445: tcp 0
18:17:22.709483 IP 172.20.6.3.60853 > 1.1.1.1.139: tcp 0
18:17:22.709556 IP 172.20.6.3.60852 > 1.1.1.1.445: tcp 0
18:17:23.709971 IP 172.20.6.3.60853 > 1.1.1.1.139: tcp 0
```

Also, note that SMB on ports 139 and 445 are actually different protocols: port 139 is SMB over NetBIOS over TCP, while 445 is SMB directly over TCP ("direct host SMB").  So if there is something preventing your Mac from using port 445, it's not just a matter of changing the port number...